# BottomSheetDialog visible in bottom even in hidden state on Android 10

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

[image: screen1]

**Explaining the image:-**

1. Login button = To show login view
2. Sign up button = To show sign up view
3. Forgot Password bottom sheet

(Image is edited to hide logos)

Problem = BottomSheetFragment is visible in bottom
Devices tested = Samsung, RealMe = both with android 10

`XML` of welcome page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".welcome.Welcome">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_welcome_content" />

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in" />

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_sign_up" />

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_forgot_password" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`xml` code using in all fragments

```
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

Also implemented this `theme` to have a custom design of sheet and have a invisible background of default sheet

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@color/trans</item>
    <item name="behavior_hideable">true</item>
    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">500dp</item>
</style>
```

Also tried this in `welcome` class

```
//using kotlin
forgotSheetBehavior.isHideable = true
forgotSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
```

Still seeing the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` in the bottom, this is not visible in the emulator of pixel with android 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to some reason

I needed to use `BottomSheetBehaviour` on every `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to hide them on start

```
//using kotlin
forgotSheetBehavior.isHideable = true
forgotSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
```

After using `BottomSheetBehaviour` on every `SheetFragment` and calling it `onCreate()` solved the problem